# send QR code to email in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

It's that possible send QR code to email in ionic 3? I can't send my QR code to email and it's show 'unable attach file'.

here's my code in html

```
 <ion-card *ngIf="createdCode">
      <ngx-qrcode *ngIf="createdCode" [qrc-value]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>Value: {{createdCode}}</p>
      </ion-card-content>
      <button ion-button (click)="sendEmail()">Send Email</button>
  </ion-card>
```

and my .ts file

```
sendEmail(){

        this.createdCode.then(ImageData);

        let email = {
            to: '',
            cc: '',
            attachments: [
                this.createdCode
            ],
            subject: 'New QR code',
            body:'this is new qrcode for student <br><br>',
            isHtml: true
        };

        this.emailComposer.open(email);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You ca not send the QR code directly as as attachment. You should first encode the QR code data into base64 and then attach it to email.
here is the Official documentation on [how to convert to base64](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i really not clear how to implement it, i just followed the steps in official documentation but it's seem the result it's a same.